# Nodejs, the Readable stream, does not emit 'end' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, streaming, buffer

I create a `Buffer` and a `Readable` stream, with the aim to make the `Readable` consume the `Buffer`.

**The code is like so:**

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

// create a Buffer and allocate 200 positions to add the long text
const buf = Buffer.alloc(200, 'this is a loooong text..');


const readStream = (buf_data) => {
return new Readable({
  read(size){
    // I push the chunk data to the stream
    this.push(buf_data);

    // Here there MUST be a condition that will `push(null)` 
    // end emit the 'end' event
    // ????
  }
})
}

// Pass the Buffer to the readable stream
read = readStream(buf)


// the 'data' event is called to print the chunk data
read.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('chnk:', chunk.toString())
})

// the 'end' event, currently is not emitted, and the reading is not stopping.
read.on('and', (chunk) => {
 console.log('--end--')
})
```

### When i run the app (node `<filename>`), the application keeps reading and printing the `text`.
There should be a condition that i can add into the `read()` method, to make `end` event trigger**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just manually emitting the `end` event after creating the stream

```
let buffer = Buffer.from(attach.base64Data, 'base64');
const bufferStream = Readable.from(buffer)
bufferStream.emit("end");
```

It's also worth noting that I was stumped for a while because I was listening for `finished` instead of `end`

```
.on('end',()=>{}) // this gets called
.on('finish',()=>{}) // this never gets called.
```